# PGPOOL ii always stand by server status unused how i can make both nodes work?

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

i implement streaming async replication between two postgreSQL 14 , and i installed and configure pgpool ii on third server , i try to send quires via pgpool and works fine but all quires returned from master server and stand by server status always unused
[image]